# how to set the html/css pages for the better view on all web browsers?

Tags: css

i've created some pages using css, but on viewing the page through different browsers it appeared as irregular arrangement of contents..

Comment: 1) Did you include a `!DOCTYPE`?  (2) Can you post anything you've done (links are fine) so we can see where you're at?  (3) See: http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to be more specific than this.

- Which browsers display the page 'correctly' and which don't? Some older browsers have... *dubious* CSS support, and some of the things that work well in IE8/FF3.5 won't work in IE6/FF1.
- Which CSS properties are you using & having trouble with? I take it you're talking about position or float or similar since you refer to an "irregular arrangement of contents", but that doesn't narrow it down all that much.
- Are some browsers displaying the page as if there's no CSS being applied at all? It's possible you've got your stylesheet link a little wrong, and some browsers are 'fixing' it for you and some are just not loading the sheet at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you potentially have more than one problem. Browser interoperability isn't going to be as easy as doing a setting. You have to compare some of the browser compatibilities and change your code to get it to look perfect in all browsers (if indeed such a nirvana is achievable for all page designs).

One thing you could try is a CSS reset such as [MeyerWeb](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). This will remove some of the defaults that the browsers do not share - therefore potentially giving you similar looking pages from which, you can adapt to look as you want them too again.

There are other methods, including comparing all the differences. But unfortunately, my point is that this isn't likely to be a quick fix without knowing more about the specific issues your having.